# When does an MSMQ message end up in the Dead Letter queue?

Tags: msmq

What circumstances would cause an MSMQ message to appear in either of the dead letter message queues?

It can happen if an application sends a transactional message to a non-transactional queue or vice versa. Are there any other reasons a message could appear there?

Answer (score 1):

You could find the most thorough answer [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2010/01/22/why-does-msmq-keep-losing-my-messages.aspx). As long as Negative source journaling is configured, failed messages due to reasons introduced in link should end up dead letter message queue.